# How to CSS override the shadow/glow of the active header/tab in jquery Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, colors, accordion, shadow

I have built an accordion using your excellent website, and it replaced my old Ajax Script that did not work with my newly applied SSL.

I am having a problem in esthetics. When a header of the accordion is active/selected, it produces a blue shadow/glow around the background. 
The default color of the glow clashes with my color scheme. I want to enforce my specific glow/shadow that works.

Could someone please help me insert the right CSS for the said new color?

Here are the scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content"
});
} );
</script>
```

Screen grab of active accordion tab:

[image: screen grab of active accordion tab]

Comment: If the effect is being added by the CSS, then use CSS to override it... not JQuery. Also, we need to see the CSS to know how its being added so we can help you change it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your CSS file that is related to this page. (change the #000 for the color of your choice.)  something like :

```
.accordion:active{

  border: 1px solid #000; 

}
```

or

```
.accordion:active{

  border: none; 

}
```

EDIT:

try this, once your css does not produce the 404.

```
.ui-accordion-header {
color: #990066;
box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 13px #906;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and

```
 .ui-accordion-header:active {
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: I included what you suggested but it did not work.  I tried to do this but it did not work either.  I believe the CSS should specify the glow around the box or tab, though I could be wrong:

        .accordion:active{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 6px 13px #906;
        }

Comment: You can first try to add !important; but it would be better to look at your inspector, right click on the object IN the inpector and copy the selector and paste it instead of the .accordion:active.  All you need is the correct selector.  We are a bit in the dark, since we don't have the whole thing. EDIT: Maybe post your CSS too.

Comment: I will try !important tomorrow since I am on EST.  Below is the code for the active tab.  I'll add the CSS of Accordion below this comment.
 
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active" role="tab" id="ui-id-3" aria-controls="ui-id-4" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Approach to History</h3>

Comment: .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active { background: #999; 
}
.ui-accordion-header {
        color: #990066;
}
.ui-accordion-content {
        color: #000;
}
.accordion:active{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 6px 13px #906;
}

Comment: Is this on a live site?  If it is, could I get a link?

Comment: The live site is https://phoenicia.org and the accordion is on the homepage only.

Comment: the first thing I noticed is the error : `GET https://phoenicia.org/resources/demos/style.css`  check the CSS file is located in the right place

Comment: True.  I removed it all together and it did not impact the page.

Comment: in your CSS, on line 981 change the ` border: 1px solid #003eff; ` to `border: none;`  that will remove the dark blue boder.  Also, look for :focus I can't see the whole CSS but the light blue border seems to be triggered by focus.  look for the same classes with `:focus`.

Comment: so did it work?  you could try `.ui-accordion-header:focus{
   outline:none !important;}` then remove the !important when possible